Using Puppeteer to put tabs into groups
I want to use puppeteer to open a set of pages at different screenwidths (IE, open url-1 and url-2 at 360, 758 and 1024px) to quickly check that my site matches the designs.
I'd like to then put the tabs for each page into their own labelled tab group.
I used createCDPSession in the hopes of accessing an API that could put the tabs into groups. It looks as though the extensions API can control tabs with chrome.tabs. However, CDPSession accesses the devtools protocol. The CDP has an extensions domain, but that does not appear to be the same API as the extensions API which accesses chrome.tabs.
Is there a way to access this API or similar via puppeteer?
